# SQL Server - Insert record count into table

Tags: sql-server

I need to execute this script monthly to load a record count into at table:

```
select count([BG_BUG_ID]) 
from [uc_maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG]
```

I created a table with one column to contain the numeric output:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BG_BUG_ID]
(
    [BG_BUD_ID_COUNT] [numeric](18, 0) NULL
)
```

I receive an error on the select statement when I execute the script below:

```
INSERT INTO [AdminDB].[dbo].[BG_BUG_ID](count)
VALUES (SELECT COUNT([BG_BUG_ID]) 
        FROM [uc_maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG])
```

What am I doing wrong? The select runs fine on its own. Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

I need to make this insert into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have mentioned wrong column name `count` instead of
  `BG_BUD_ID_COUNT`.
- Remove keyword `values`.

Try like below

```
INSERT INTO [AdminDB].[dbo].[BG_BUG_ID](BG_BUD_ID_COUNT)
SELECT COUNT([BG_BUG_ID])
FROM [uc_maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `values`:

```
Insert into [AdminDB].[dbo].[BG_BUG_ID](BG_BUD_ID_COUNT)
select count([BG_BUG_ID])
from [uc_maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO [AdminDB].[dbo].[BG_BUG_ID]
SELECT COUNT([BG_BUG_ID]) 
        FROM [uc_maint_maintenance_db].[td].[BUG]
```